# Admob ads alignment issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am adding ad at bottom of screen but ad is about 10dp above from bottom  which gives really weird look. I have checked all related questions but I couldn't find answer. Here is my code

```
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/admobAd"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="***********"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     />
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Here is my complete xml

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ton"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Test1"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Test2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:textSize="12dp" >
</TextView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="******"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post your entire xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have modified your xml try using this.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ton"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Test1"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:textSize="12dp" >
    </TextView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="******"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I Have removed android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" from your relative layout ..try this out

Comment: If this worked please mark this as an answer so that other people don try to debug again....cheers

Comment: thanks @archon92. My mistake that I didn't notice this before posting question.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the position of your Admob banner to the bottom of the screen. Refer below code, may be this might help you -

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
  .build();

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mFrameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
   AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 // align bottom
adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
 // align center
adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


relativeLayout.addView(adView, adViewParams);


adView.loadAd(adRequest);
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
adView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Cheers :)

Comment: thanks @ashish for your effort. But it did't solve my problem. As I mentioned earlier, it almost at bottom of screen but not exactly (around 10dp) above to exact buttom